# How to use Sql Server Soundex

Tags: sql-server, search, sql-server-2014

When I say SOUNDEX there is a view there is no ST (nvarchar) column in this shower, the results don't come. How should I use this?

```
SELECT * FROM SearcView where SOUNDEX('searcKey') = SOUNDEX(ST)


SELECT * FROM SearcView WHERE ST LIKE '%1300 01%'
```

I'm getting a result.
but

```
ST LIKE '%130001%'
```

doesn't work when I enter

```
----------------------------------------------------
|ST                                                 |
-----------------------------------------------------
| A10101CompressorRENAULT50212090071300 010 001     |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

I want to solve this with SOUNDEX

Comment: What are you trying to compare `'searcKey'` to?  If there is no column `ST` in `SearcView` then you need to choose a different column.

Comment: 'searcKey' I enter the word to search here

Comment: Your question makes no sense to me, can you clean it up a bit?

Comment: Here I want to return a clever result

Comment: I'm still a little unclear on what you are asking, but from what I can tell I think you're going about this wrong.  `SOUNDEX` and `LIKE` perform completely different functions.  If `ST LIKE '%130001%'` does not give you the results you are looking for, you need to change your search pattern, not the function you  use to search.  `SOUNDEX` tells you if two strings are _audibly_  similar - meaning they _sound_ similar when spoken.  You still want to use `LIKE` in your query.

Comment: thank you. I understood properly now.
Is there a function or a technology that can solve this problem?(except like)

Comment: There might be, but I've never researched it.  Why are you looking for something other than `LIKE`?  Why can you not just update your search pattern?

Comment: The search is not appropriate to the word data structure.
The data structure does not change because of its original structure.

Comment: Are you just wanting to ignore spaces in the where clause? SOUNDEX is 100% the wrong tool here.